# Create Slideshow video by merge png and jpeg images and audio files using ffmpeg on linux

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, slideshow

I am creating slideshow video using png,jpeg and audio files the issue i am getting is the at a time only either i have to use png or jpeg but i want to used both so how can i do this here are my list of commands which i am trying. Please help me regards this.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg '-framerate' '1/27' '-pattern_type' 'glob' '-i' '/var/www/html/phpvideotoolkit-v2-master/examples/media/images/*.jpg' '-i' '/var/www/html/phpvideotoolkit-v2-master/examples/media/1.mp3' '-pix_fmt' 'yuv420p' '-shortest' '-y' '-q' '4' '-strict' 'experimental' '-threads' '1' '-acodec' 'aac' '-ar' '22050' '-vcodec' 'mpeg4' '-s' '320x240' '/var/www/html/ffmpe/1.mp4'
```

By doing this i am only able to create jpg images video but i want to both.

i have used concat command also but not getting any output i have read about some filter but how to used with images i dont know so could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg supports piping of image sequences, so if you enable extended globbing it's simple enough to get all files ending in either `.jpg` or `.png`. However, FFmpeg seems to get confused if you pass it a mix of formats, so it's better to convert (using ImageMagick in this case) all images to PNG and then pass them on.

As you can see, all the images, even those already being PNG, will get converted. This is a bit inefficient, but unless you have lots of large images it shouldn't be too bad.
`-quality 01` in the IM command makes sure the images are only minimally compressed. It makes little sense to spend a lot of time and effort on compression when FFmpeg will decompress immediately afterwards.

```
shopt -s extglob

convert \
/var/www/html/phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\
/examples/media/images/*+(.jpg|.png) -quality 01 png:- |\
  /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/27 \
  -f image2pipe -i - \
  -i /var/www/html/phpvideotoolkit-v2-master/examples/media/1.mp3 \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -shortest -q 4 -strict experimental -threads 1 \
  -acodec aac -ar 22050 \
  -vcodec mpeg4 -s 320x240 /var/www/html/ffmpe/1.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @aksela i will try and get back to you.